# Compare string in one txt file to string in another

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I'm working on a script that will be used in a daily automation.

I have 2 files, one is a static file containing a list of cusips.  The 2nd file is a data file that looks something like this:

```xml
<Imports/>
<InterpretFXRates/>
<SCXList date="20170309">
<SCX type="cs" iso="USD" symbol="SPLS" cusip="855030102" name="STAPLES INC COM" issuer="us" record="20170324" maturity="20170413" intdiv=".48" sap="NR" moody="NR" apinternalid="USD855030102" action="a"/>
<SCX type="cs" iso="USD" symbol="ARE" cusip="015271109" name="ALEXANDRIA REAL ESTATE EQUITIES INC COM" issuer="us" record="20170331" maturity="20170417" intdiv="3.32" sap="NR" moody="NR" apinternalid="USD015271109" action="a"/>
<SCX type="cs" iso="USD" symbol="AMGN" cusip="031162100" name="AMGEN INC COM" issuer="us" record="20170517" maturity="20170608" intdiv="4.6" sap="NR" moody="NR" apinternalid="USD031162100" action="a"/>
```

So what I'm trying to do is to iterate through each cusip of the static file and check to see if it is in any of the lines above.  If it is found, then we will delete the line from the new file.

```
import csv

bond_list = 'BondFilterList.txt'  #containes list of cusips
dataport_file = 'test.scx'        #contained the <SCX... data
output_file = 'out.scx'

data = []

with open(bond_list, 'r') as bl, open(dataport_file, 'r') as df:

    for cusip in bl:
        lines = [y.strip() for y in df]
        for line in lines:
            if cusip in line:
                print("Matched")
            else:
                data.append(line)


with open(output_file, "w") as output:
     writer = csv.writer(output, lineterminator = '\n', escapechar = ' ',     quoting = csv.QUOTE_NONE)
     for x in data:
         writer.writerow([x])

output.close
```

I'm definitely missing something because my `if` statement is always returning `False`.

Comment: your inner loop `for line in (y.strip() for y in df):` consumes the file iterator on first iteration. Create a list instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
for cusip in bl:
    for line in (y.strip() for y in df):
```

this is a double loop on 2 file iterators. The inner loop works fine only the first time. The other times it doesn't even enter because `df` reached end of file.

Rewrite:

```
lines = [y.strip() for y in df]  # listcomp not gencomp: compute a real list
for cusip in bl:
    for line in lines:
```

Comment: thank you, for some reason, I'm still not able to get any matches and the if statement is returning false on every line

Comment: I would `print(cusip,line)` just before `if cusip in line:`. That should be educational.

Comment: Jackpot! Thanks for the guidance!

Answer (score 0):

Here is my final code, thanks again for the help Jean.

```
import csv

bond_list = 'BondFilterList.txt'  #containes list of cusips
dataport_file = 'test.scx'        #contained the <SCX... data
output_file = 'out.scx'

data = []

with open(bond_list, 'r') as bl, open(dataport_file, 'r') as df:
    lines = [y.strip() for y in df]
    cusips = [cusip.upper().strip() for cusip in bl]

    for line in lines:    
         if not any(cusip in line for cusip in cusips):                
            data.append(line)

with open(output_file, "w") as output:
     writer = csv.writer(output, lineterminator = '\n', escapechar = ' ', quoting = csv.QUOTE_NONE)
     for x in data:
         writer.writerow([x])

output.close
```